# Don't see the cube under layout instead i see key frames. How can i get back the layout screen in 2.9

Tags: keyframes

[image: Blender_layout]This is my 3rd day in Blender 2.9. When I go to the blender Layout tab I see the keyframes. When I tried to pull it down by holding the corner I get more layers of keyframes. How do I get back to the default screen that shows the cube? Here is the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the little clock icon in the top left corner of Blender's window (arrowed below).
[image]

That will bring up the window selector and you can click on 3D Viewport to bring back your editing window:
[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you @John Eason